# Wcf Rest Call HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request or HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: rest, wcf

I am having trouble while sending the request to a rest service. The service works fine on my desktop, but getting the following error when i host on the IIS.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request when i use https

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found when i use http

Here is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<webHttpBinding>
<binding name="webBinding">
<security mode="Transport">
</security>
</binding>
</webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
<service     
behaviorConfiguration="CoreService.DialService.DialServiceBehavior" 
name="CoreService.DialService.TelephonyService">
<endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="webBinding" 
contract="CoreService.DialService.ITelephonyService"/>
</service>
</services>
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
<behavior name="webBehavior">
<webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
<serviceBehaviors> 
<behavior name="CoreService.DialService.DialServiceBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
<add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<diagnostics>
<messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" 
logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
maxMessagesToLog="3000" maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
</diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service Contract

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Dial", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = 
    WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [OperationContract]
    Objects.Response.Telephony.DialResponse 
    Dial(Objects.Request.Telephony.DialRequest request);
```

Here is the client

```
DialRequest DialRequest = new DialRequest();
DialResponse DialResponse = new DialResponse();

DialRequest.ProjectID = "AMS0103300";
DialRequest.DialFromExtension = "1234";
DialRequest.OutDialCode = "51";
DialRequest.RequestBy = "HC User";
DialRequest.DialToPhoneNumber = "1234567890";
DialRequest.RequestDate = DateTime.Now;
DialRequest.ApplicationID = Guid.Parse("F5EE534B-B5ED-4ADD-B671- 
CCF7C05057A7");


DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
new 
DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Objects.Request.Telephony.DialRequest));

MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
ser.WriteObject(mem, DialRequest);
string data =
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(mem.ToArray(), 0, (int)mem.Length);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;


var result = webClient.UploadString("https://test.xxxx.com/DialService/TelephonyService.svc/Dial","POST", data);
```

I have tried with different values in protocolMapping, but the results are same. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are no errors in you project. Besides protocol mapping is the new feature in Net4.5, which could help us simplify settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/simplified-configuration
[How to make WCF Service Use HTTPS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380024/how-to-make-wcf-service-use-https-protocol/55389579#55389579)
There might be some small problems during the process of hosting the service on the IIS. 
Could you access the WSDL page successfully?
Like the following form.
[image]
We might need to enable the WCF feature in the control panel.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivP92.png]
I have made an example, wish it is useful to you.
**Server-side (WCF service application).**
**IService1**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate ="/MyTest",Method ="POST",RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string Test(CompositeType compositeType);
}
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"The BoolValue is {boolValue}, StringValue is {stringValue}";
        }
    }
```

**Service1.svc.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }

    public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
    {
        if (composite == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
        }
        if (composite.BoolValue)
        {
            composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
        }
        return composite;
    }

    public string Test(CompositeType compositeType)
    {
        return compositeType.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**IIS(new website)**
[image]
**Client(generate the data contract by adding service reference)**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //for validating the self-signed certificated.
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
              {
                  return true;
              };
            ServiceReference1.CompositeType composite = new ServiceReference1.CompositeType()
            {
                StringValue = "Hello",
                BoolValue = true
            };
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServiceReference1.CompositeType));

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, composite);
            string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray(), 0, (int)ms.Length);

            WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
            webclient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var result = webclient.UploadString("https://localhost:8734/service1.svc/MyTest", "POST", data);
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            WebClient webclient2 = new WebClient();
            webclient2.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
            webclient2.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            var result2 = webclient2.UploadString("http://localhost:8733/service1.svc/MyTest", "POST", data);
            Console.WriteLine(result2);

        }
```

**Result.**
[image]
Besides, PostMan is good choice to test Rest style service.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Hi Abraham, Thank you for your response. Yes, i can access the wsdl without any issues. I am not sure what is wrong with my config.

Comment: After you published the service on the IIS, could you access the other operations decorated by the [WebGet] in the browser? if not have a Get operation, try to add one for testing the service.

Comment: Update: I was able to access the other methods, but the only problem is while sending json request. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: try to use my configuration, and publish it again.  If it happened to bad request, try to check the request entity.  At last, I suggest you check whether the request is being processed properly by coming into Debug mode.