# I am getting error 404 on run WCF services. web-services don't work on live Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis-7

I have a WCF service created with VS2013 on Win8. If I start the service via VS (localhost:port) I'm able to do GET response in json

but same service i am hosted on server (IIS7) then i get 404 Error

localhost URL : http://localhost:43596/abc.svc/LoginUser/abc/abc

Live URL: http://mywwebsite.com:80/abc.svc/LoginUser/abc/abc

Comment: Please post your Web.config

Comment: The HTTP 404 Not Found Error means that the webpage you were trying to reach could not be found on the server. It ultimately means that the server has not been set up correctly and the route to the WCF service cannot be found.

Comment: @betelgeuce suggest me about server configuration for wcf services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opionio, there might something amiss with the hosting environment, try to enable WCF feature support in IIS.
[image]
[image]
Here is my service, wish it is useful to you.
**IService1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    string GetData(int value);
```

**Service1.svc.**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http"/>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" bindingConfiguration="mybinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Since the above configuration support both http and https protocol, we need to add http and https binding in IIS site binding module.
[image]
[image]
Reference.
[How to make WCF Service Use HTTPS protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380024/how-to-make-wcf-service-use-https-protocol/55389579#55389579)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.