# Configure WCF service in Azure Container Apps

Tags: docker, wcf, azure-container-apps, corewcf

I'm trying to deploy a WCF service implemented using CoreWCF + .NET 6 to Azure Container Apps exposing https endpoints from a linux container.

I try the same service using http protocol and everything work correctly.

I also expose a gRPC service, but the difference with WCF is the binding configuration. WCF needs to set up the same protocol schema for both client and server. So I suppose it's not possible redirect an https request to a container that expose a WCF service on the port 80. This can be done with REST or gRPC service instead.

I enable ingress in Azure Container Apps and set the port 443. When I try the http endpoint I set the port 80 instead.

The binding of the WCF is BasicHttpBinding with security mode Transport. When i try the http endpoint I set security mode None.

In the dockefile I expose port 80 and 443.

On my local machine I'm able to get thing work because i can use a self signed certificate, but in a production enviroment this doesn't seems to work. I deploy the self signed certificate with the container image, but maybe there isn't a certification authority that can trust this certificate.

I read that for Azure Container Instance it's possible to configure https running Ngix in a sidecar container. But in this case the request is redirected internally on port 80 and so it doesn't work for me.

What can i do for get my service work over https?

Comment: You can check whether the answer to [this Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55380024/how-to-make-wcf-service-use-https-protocol) is helpful to you. Also [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security?redirectedfrom=MSDN) may provide some useful information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I try to see your link but my case is a little different. I have to deploy the WCF service in a container inside a host that I cannot handle directly because is managed by Azure Container Apps. So I cannot install a self signed certificate.

Comment: @Akite could you please share your Dockerfile?